# How does bash parse quotes in this example?

Tags: bash

I am running an example and trying to figure out how the arguments were parsed.

```
colour1="red"
colour2="light blue"
colour3="dark green"

for X in "$colour1" $colour2" $colour3"
do
    echo $X
done
```

Note that the weird missing quotes are not a typo. It's just a test example from a blog.

The output I get is

> red
>
> light
>
> blue dark green

The output I expected was

> red
>
> light
>
> blue
>
> dark green

since colour2 won't be protected by quotes but colour1 and colour3 should be. What is the interpreter doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$colour2` and `"$ colour3"` are immediately adjacent, they form a single word before parameter expansion occurs. Here's how the expansion progresses:

1. You start with `$colour2" $colour3"`
2. Parameter expansion turns this into `light blue" dark green"`
3. Word-splitting is applied to the result of the expansion on *unquoted* whitespace. As there is only one unquoted space, the two resulting words are `light` and `blue" dark green"`.
4. Finally quote removal is performed, yielding `light` and `blue dark green`.